# Is there a list of US Airports with the kiosks for ESTA arrivals?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, airports, esta

Evidently, [LAX (at least the Tom Bradley Terminal)](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2014/10/why-us-customs-queues-are-now-a-lot-less-painful/) now has kiosks to process ESTA arrivals, instead of the traditional 100-person queues we're used to seeing.

However, the author is unclear which other airports this has been implemented at.

As an occasional traveller to the US, usually the west coast, I'm keen to find out which airports have this, and if there's a list on line on the TSA site or other?

Comment: They have them in Dallas, Chicago, Orlando and perhaps other cities.  Not sure where you would find a comprehensive list as the system is still being rolled out.  Now we have to wait to see how long before US citizens start complaining about foreigners clearing immigration faster.

Comment: @Tom: That's an easy problem to solve.  `sleep(rand(300))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the list for airports equipped with **Automated Passport Control (APC)** to serve ESTA holders in addition to US and Canadian passports holders, from the [U.S Customs and Border Protection Official website](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc) as of now:

- Albuquerque International Airport (ABQ)
- Charlotte Douglas International Airport (CLT)
- Denver International Airport (DEN)
- Edmonton International Airport (YEG)
- Halifax Stanfield International Airport (YHZ)
- Kansas City International Airport (MCI)
- Kona International Airport (KOA)
- Montréal - Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport (YUL)
- Oakland International Airport (OAK)
- Ontario International Airport (ONT)
- San Juan Seaport (PUE)
- Philadelphia International Airport (PHL)
- Phoenix Sky Harbor International Airport (PHX)
- Pittsburgh International Airport (PIT)
- Portland International Airport (PDX)
- Raleigh-Durham International Airport (RDU)
- Salt Lake City International Airport (SLC)
- Saipan International Airport (SPN)
- Seattle Sea-Tac Airport (SEA)
- Southwest Florida International Airport (RSW)
- Luis Muñoz Marín International Airport (SJU)
- Tampa International Airport (TPA)
- T.F. Green International Airport (PVD)
- Vancouver Seaport (YHC)
- William P. Hobby International Airport (HOU)

Comment: No SFO yet, damn :/

Comment: @MarkMayo give it sometime and it will spread all over int'l airports in the US.

Comment: IAH doesn't have them yet. They're all neatly packed near the massive immigration queue but covered in plastic and not turned on.

Comment: @MarkMayo They're in SFO now, though that probably doesn't help you much...